# Oracle 10g - How to prevent one user from hogging all resources?

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

I am wondering if there is any way to limit how much resources one user can take on my Oracle system. I want to limit some queries and systems from being able to hog all system resources when they run non optimized queries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a built-in utility called **Resource Manager** exactly for that purpose:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/dbrm.htm#i1010776

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for something simpler than the resource manager, try [Profiles](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/network.101/b10773/admusers.htm#1012779).

I haven't had much success with the resource manager. In my experience with it I've found that it's easier to give priority over resources to certain users than to limit users.

Comment: Isn't Profiles just a part of Resource Manager (per your link)?

Comment: No.
Profiles is a much more basic way of limiting resource than the resource manager.
[This](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6010.htm#sthref5226) might be a better link.

Comment: Profiles are indeed simpler, but they work much differently than resource manager.  Profiles use intrinsic limits with no notion of the condition of the database or whether the statement/session will have any significant impact on performance at all.  For example, if a statement exceeds the CPU_PER_CALL, it returns an error even if the execution would have little impact on the system.

Comment: Resource Manager on the other hand doesn't do anything if the statement could complete without impacting the overall system even if that means it uses 99.9% of the CPU.  From the documentation: "When every group can secure as much CPU resources as it demands, the Database Resource Manager first seeks to maximize system throughput, not to enforce allocation percentages."

Comment: When the system will need to prioritize, sessions may get switched to different consumer groups to limit their resource utilization, but unless specified the statements will not throw errors just run slower.

Comment: Additionally you should note that with Profiles session limits such as CPU_PER_SESSION are from the time the user logs in, so very low impact queries run infrequently could over time cause this limit to be exceeded and the statement to fail.